# Azure Mobile Services and Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I hava added Azure Application Insights to a new Azure Mobile Services (.NET backend) project. When I running it on my local machine it's sending data to insights. But when I deploy it to Azure it will not work. In the log at the portal I get the message below. Anyone that know how to solve this?

> Message='Could not load assembly 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x86.dll'. Error received: 'Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x86.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.'.', Exception=System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x86.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>   File name: 'file:///D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensions.Intercept_x86.dll'
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Config.WebHostAssemblyResolver.LoadAssembly(String assemblyFilePath)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Config.WebHostAssemblyResolver.GetApplicationAssemblies(ICollection`1 asmPaths, ISet`1 excludedAssemblyNames)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>   , Id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Category='Service.Hosting'

Comment: Did you add Application Insights manually through Nuget or from the Visual Studio Application Insights Command? Which VS version are you using?

Comment: I right click the project and added application insights. To track custom event working. I guess the problem is that mobile services ignoring web.config. But havn't found a way to add requst tracking in code.

Comment: If you are saying that web.config is ignored request monitoring will definitely not work. You can try to register http module manually. Http module type is Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTracking.WebRequestTrackingModule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is a first chance exception and does not affect monitoring in general. AI does not work because Azure Mobile Services infrastructure blocks http module so application insights http module cannot be loaded. There is no workaround how you could enable autocollection right now. You can only manually instrument your code.